# Lining up left Floating Div's to look like a table

Tags: html

I'm trying to line up these div's, but it seems to not be working correctly.

the web address is - http://www.minvera.com/hosting-price-sheet

I need all the div's to line up because it's supposed to be similar to a table, but I hate tables.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post code not links.

Comment: That's tabular data which is *exactly* what tables are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table is a table and if you want to make a table yous should actually make a table :-) Tables are not bad per se. Ommiting a table just because you dont like tables is wrong. On the other side you are using `<br>` which should be avoided.

Whatever: If you open up your code between your rows you have some `<p>` and inside those you have `<br>` between some links without text.

Remove those `<br>` and your table looks correct. Those `<p>` are actually over the full width of your container and therefore are pushing down subsequently the following divs. Maybe they are from some html editor? If you need the links in separated lines make them `display:block`

It's hard for me to see why you need it that way, because I would have placed my divs differently.

Comment: Is it possible to make the tables column width a percentage?

Comment: Yes, that works but remember that the percentage is in relation to the container element. I would suggest switching to tables because that's what they are used for and you will have a lot(!) less code and it is more readable.

Comment: Thank you. Once I get more reputation, I will up-vote!

Answer (score 0):

Your div are seperated by a paragraph

and in contain a 
 wich make the line break. Also there always a line break after the paragraph so you have to play with the padding and the margin to remove it.

Hope this help.

You can also use display:inline-block; on each div to make them side by side (work without float).